# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have started coding simple Spring Boot app, and got some issues. I have controller, home.html page which shows Hello Home Page.

**This is the Error:**

```
 Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.createHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:341)
The following method did not exist:
    'void org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod.<init>(java.lang.String, org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory, org.springframework.context.MessageSource, java.lang.reflect.Method)'

Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod
Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Pom.xml**

There is only dependency code from pom.xml

```
<project>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**MainController**

MainController code from controller package

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String greeting(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("title", "Home Page");
        return "home";
    }

}
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title th:text="${title}"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${title} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

**MillionApplication**

Default method from

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MillionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MillionApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Had someone have similar issues ?
Can someone help me because i tried so many things and nothing worked

Comment: Which spring-boot version do you use?

Comment: Remove the spring-web dependency, spring-boot-starter-web already includes the correct version of that.

Answer (score 1):

You have `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency which has `spring-web` as a transitive dependency, so you don't need `spring-web` to explicitly defined in your `pom.xml`. Additionally, you should rely on the transitive dependencies and versions of Spring Boot Starters instead of defining versions on your own (as you did with `spring-web`).
Having said that, please delete the following dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It doesn't help

Comment: It must, the error message is pretty clear: "Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod". Please recompile the code using `mvn clean package`.